# linq inner join extension for multiple lists (Generic way)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, inner-join

I want to know about is there any way to do Joining multiple list using Linq (Generic way).

I just create a generic method for joining 2 List

```
public static T Merge<T>(T List1, T List2) where T : new()
        {
            var properties = typeof(T)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && !p.GetIndexParameters().Any());

            T result = new T();

            foreach (var prop in properties)
            {
                object value = prop.GetValue(List1) ?? prop.GetValue(List2);
                prop.SetValue(result, value);
            }

            return result;
        }

List<student> _List1 = List1.Cast<student>().ToList();
List<student> _List2 = List2.Cast<student>().ToList();
var mergedlist = from a in _List1
    join b in _List2
    on a.stid equals b.stid 
    select Merge(a, b);
```

sample data

```
public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int IdAddress { get; set; }
        public Person(int ID, string Name,int IdAddress)
        {
            this.IdAddress = IdAddress;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.ID = ID;
        }
    }

public class Address
{
    public int IdAddress { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public Address( int IdAddress,string Street)
    {
        this.IdAddress = IdAddress;
        this.Street = Street;
    }
}
```

### inputs

```
List<Person> _List1 = person list
List<Address> _List2 = address list
var List<List<TModel>>groupedList=new List<List<TModel>>();
groupedList.add(_List1);
groupedList.add(_List2);

var Result= Merge(groupedList,/*Grouping condition*/,/*resultsetdetails*/);
```

But i need to pass multiple List of List into Merge function .How we can achieve ?

How we can do using TModel ?

Comment: If both lists have items of the same type, why don't use [`Union`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?view=netcore-3.1) method for example? Or [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__) if types are different

Comment: i need to pass multiple typed lists into function merge. current function return student type list based on property  value null or not.

Comment: @JishnuChandran if [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__) as Pavel suggests doesn't work for you, then what do you actually mean by "Joining multiple lists"? Can you show example input and expected output?

Comment: @Xerillio Hi ,added more details .can you please look into this.need to pass List of another lists

Comment: @JishnuChandran I understand you want to merge multiple lists, but how do you merge a `Person` and an `Address`? There's no logic (for me) in that. Please show some actual data as input and output. That will help us understand what it means to merge `List<Person>` with `List<Address>`.

Answer (score 1):

> I just create a generic method for joining 2 List

No, you created method that merges two objects.

If you need to join many lists, you can do it the same way you join two lists, just use `Aggregate`

```
List<Person> _List1 = new List<Person>();
List<Address> _List2 = new List<Address>();
var groupedList = new List<IEnumerable<TModel>>
{
    _List1,
    _List2
};

IEnumerable<TModel> aggr = groupedList.Aggregate((listA, listB) => 
                                from a in listA
                                join b in listB
                                on a.stid equals b.stid
                                select Merge(a, b));
```